# Generate random numbers in R satisfying constraints

Tags: r, random, constraints

I need help with a code to generate random numbers according to constraints. 
Specifically, I am trying to simulate random numbers ALFA and BETA from, respectively, a Normal and a Gamma distribution such that ALFA - BETA < 1.

Here is what I have written but it does not work at all.

```
set.seed(42) 
n <- 0 
repeat {
  n <- n + 1
  a <- rnorm(1, 10, 2)
  b <- rgamma(1, 8, 1)
  d <- a - b
  if (d < 1) 
  alfa[n] <- a
  beta[n] <- b
  l = length(alfa)
  if (l == 10000) break
}
```

Comment: You should use curly braces `{}` after your first `if` statement to enclose the dependent lines. By default, only the first line after the `if` will depend on the `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to vectorization, it will be faster to generate the numbers "all at once"  rather than in a loop:

```
set.seed(42)
N = 1e5
a = rnorm(N, 10, 2)
b = rgamma(N, 8, 1)
d = a - b
alfa = a[d < 1]
beta = b[d < 1]
length(alfa)
# [1] 36436
```

This generated 100,000 candidates, 36,436 of which met your criteria. If you want to generate `n` samples, try setting `N = 4 * n` and you'll probably generate more than enough, keep the first `n`.

---

Your loop has 2 problems: (a) you need curly braces to enclose multiple lines after an `if` statement. (b) you are using `n` as an attempt counter, but it should be a success counter. As written, your loop will only stop if the 10000th attempt is a success. Move `n <- n + 1` inside the `if` statement to fix:

```
set.seed(42) 
n <- 0 
alfa = numeric(0)
beta = numeric(0)
repeat {
  a <- rnorm(1, 10, 2)
  b <- rgamma(1, 8, 1)
  d <- a - b
  if (d < 1) {
    n <- n + 1
    alfa[n] <- a
    beta[n] <- b
    l = length(alfa)
    if (l == 500) break
  }
}
```

But the first way is better... due to "growing" `alfa` and `beta` in the loop, and generating numbers one at a time, this method takes longer to generate 500 numbers than the code above takes to generate 30,000.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion on computational time. It worked properly and, as you suggested, I generated N = 4*n of them and kept how many needed.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Gregor Thomas, the failure of your attempt is due to the missing of curly braces to enclose the `if` statement. If you would like to skip `{}` for `if` control, maybe you can try the code below

```
set.seed(42) 
r <- list()
repeat {
  a <- rnorm(1, 10, 2)
  b <- rgamma(1, 8, 1)
  d <- a - b
  if (d < 1) r[[length(r)+1]] <- cbind(alfa = a, beta = b)
  if (length(r) == 100000) break
}
r <- do.call(rbind,r)
```

such that

```
> head(r)
          alfa      beta
[1,]  9.787751 12.210648
[2,]  9.810682 14.046190
[3,]  9.874572 11.499204
[4,]  6.473674  8.812951
[5,]  8.720010  8.799160
[6,] 11.409675 10.602608
```

Comment: It might not matter for OP but this code uses an entirely avoidable pattern that’s *very* slow because it causes runtime that’s proportional to the size of the output squared. Simply preallocating the data.frame would make the code orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks! Any advice on improving it? Appreciated in advance!

Comment: At its simplest, just preallocate two vectors and assign indices instead of growing them. To be a bit smarter, do what Gregor suggests: use vectorisation to generate the random numbers, reject those not fitting the criterion, and repeat (in progressively smaller chunks) until enough numbers have been generated: https://gist.github.com/klmr/7e52ffd8c0db7d6b71395ab1d91c9ae5

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you again!

Comment: @GregorThomas I attempted that first but unfortunately updating rows in a table is actually *really slow* (matrix might be faster but I doubt it, if the matrix is row-major). Much faster to update two vectors and to cbind them at the end.